# Combining SharedPreferences with preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Combining `SharedPreferences` with preference
I wish to use integers in setting and the app is crashing:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int car = SP.getInt("hourly_key", 0);
    int wage = SP.getInt("car_key",0);
```

**prefs_general.xml:**

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/pref_default_hourly_name"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:key="hourly_key"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_hourly_name"
    />

<EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/pref_default_car_name"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:key="car_key"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_car_name" />
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<string name="pref_title_hourly_name">Hourly wage</string>
<integer name="pref_default_hourly_name">30</integer>

<string name="pref_title_car_name">Daily car expense</string>
<integer name="pref_default_car_name">15</integer>
```

**Log:**

```
4-08 09:30:03.805 14350-14350/com.michlind.nanytime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.michlind.nanytime, PID: 14350
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.michlind.nanytime/com.michlind.nanytime.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
at com.michlind.nanytime.MainActivity.onPostResume(MainActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: show logcat output

Comment: If you have crash in your app so you should post `Required Stack Trace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `preference` type is `String` while you are loading it using `getInt()` which is wrong. you should use `getString()` instead.

**Edit**

---

for you to actually make it save the value as Integer you'll have to write your own custom class **or** else  you should use
`Integer.parseInt(pref.getString("v","9"));`

Comment: Where do you see my preference type is String? But I wish to set and get it as Int

Comment: P.S: make sure you check against null otherwise you might hit NPE